# Cannot submit my login form in yii framework

Tags: php, forms, yii

I am trying to create my First Yii application. But I cannot find a proper totorial to study this framework from A to Z. I want to ceate a login form using yii framework.
I crated a one by looking at the other exampls. But when I submit the form it says 
"include(UserIdentity.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory"

I used the model class name to get the post data in my controller

if(isset($_POST['User']))

But I am not sure what I should use in $_POST in yii framework and why? and how it works.

Pleas help me with some information for this

Answer (score 1):

I would thoroughly recommend reading http://www.yiiframework.com/tutorials/ and working through all the tutorials. They will give you a thorough grounding in how to use Yii, and many of the examples talk you through exactly the kind of things you are trying to do. Also, using the code creation tools described in the tutorials is a quick way of seeing exactly how Yii works, and how to create your own code.

Answer (score 0):

Please go with definitive guide http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/ .